# preact-material-components: how to change into mdc-theme--dark so that all descenant ctnl's change css style?

Tags: html, css, material-ui, themes, preact

I have generated preact-cli app, where I have in Header.js next code:

document.body.classList.add('mdc-theme--dark');

when a user want to change used ligth theme into the dark theme. I have seen another apps where material controls will change theme in the situation like this one. But when above code will executed, it will change only background of app!??

Must I use some kind of Theme Provider? Or must I explicit set every jsx element and if so, into which css class name / control etc I must use and which kind of css selector must be defined in css? An principal example could be very good!

Comment: I learned better use of css selectors by adding next blocks into main css file: .mdc-theme--dark {
 background-color: #333;
 color: #fff;
}

.mdc-theme--dark .mdc-card, .mdc-theme--dark .mdc-form-field, 
.mdc-theme--dark .mdc-checkbox, .mdc-theme--dark a {
 color: #FFF;
 background-color: black;
  border-color: #FFF;;
}

Comment: I had problems to change preact material select and textfield into dark css values. Some values worked, but not properly with :focus/not :focus'ed. Instead of html 5 select and input[type="text"] worked as usual.

Answer (score 0):

I found a github web address, where they are telling about this theme in [preact-material-boilerplate](https://github.com/preactjs-templates/material). From there best way to do is: [Theming](https://material.io/develop/web/theming/color#css-custom-properties), then: npm install @material/theme and change custom base color properties like in doucmentation.

And the next blog tells more about css custom properties: https://fristys.me/blog/easy-light-and-dark-mode/